# How to set Background image size

Tags: css

I set image in background but in background full image is not display . I want to set background image size so which css property i use

```
 .header

    {
       background:("/images/demo.png")no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: `background-size` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
background-size
```

From here: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This one: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

And use google next time for this :)

Answer (score 0):

This works only for CSS3. In older CSS version you need to solve it by another div with img.

```css
background-size: 800px 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header

    {
       background:("/images/demo.png")no-repeat;
       background-size:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url('image');
background-size: width height;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```